# Google Cloud Firewall Exposing Port Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform

I managed to successfully deploy a docker image to a VM instance. How can I send network requests to it?

The code is a simple Node.js / express app that simply `res.json()` "Hi there!" on the root path. It is listening on port 3000.

I think the deploy process was this:

1. Build Docker image from Node.js / express src.
2. Run container on local command line, correctly expose ports. It works locally.
3. Tagged the image with the correct project ID / zone.
4. Pushed to VM. **I Think I pushed the image, rather than the container. is this a problem?**
5. SSH into VM. Run `docker ps` and see running container with correct image tag
6. use command line `curl` (I am using zsh terminal) as well as browser to check network requests. Getting `connection refused error`

As a beginner, the google firewall settings appear to be open--I have allowed ingress on all ports.

[image]

I will also want to allow egress at some point but for now my problem is that I am getting a `connection refused error` whenever I try to contact the IP address, either with my web-browser or `curl` from the command line.

It would seem that the issue is most likely with the firewalls, and I have confirmed that my docker container is running in the VM (and the source code works on my machine).

EDIT:

Updated Firewall Rules with Port 3000 Ingress:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with 1) The command line that you are running the container. 2) Updated screenshot after you create a VPC Firewall **ingress** rule for port 3000. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls 3) Which OS are you running Docker on? Check if the **UFW** firewall is active **sudo ufw status**. 4) Note: Google has two types of Compute engines. One is designed for containers - Google Compute Engine Container-Optimized OS https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits note which in your question.

Comment: One additional item. For Docker, you must expose the TCP port when running the container. That is why your question needs to command included.

Comment: The command line of the VM or my local command line?

Comment: I remember exposing the port when building the container on my local command line for testing, but I think I `docker push`ed only the image. I SSH'd into the VM and the correct image is running as a container... is the problem that when I the VM built my pushed image into a container it didn't expose any ports? How can I tell if it's this vs if it's the firewalls?

Comment: The command that you used from the compute engine SSH session to start the Docker container. If you used other methods clearly specify that in your question.

Comment: I don't think I'm using the optimized container OS

Comment: To prevent going round and round, edit your question and clearly specify all details.

Comment: I don't recall starting the docker container in the SSH session... would it have done this for me?

Comment: For example, you are not sure if you are using COS. Did you install Docker on your VM or was it already installed? Do you specify the container why creating the VM instance, or later execute a Docker pull?

Comment: There are dozens of details. I recommend **once again** that you follow one of Google's tutorials and learn how to do things correctly. The time invested is 30 minutes, otherwise, you can waste hours/days.

Comment: What tutorial would you recommend specifically? I followed Google's Artifact Registry Docker Quick Guide https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/quickstart

Comment: Google Search is a great tool to use. There are dozens of tutorials and getting started guides. Pick one that works well for you. Note: I highly recommend Google Qwiklabs. Excellent tutorials for everything Google Cloud and you can practice on an account they provide you which minimizes mistakes. https://www.qwiklabs.com/

Comment: Search Qwiklabs for **Introduction to Docker**.

Answer (score 1):

You need a firewall rule that permits traffic to `tcp:3000`.

Preferably from just your host's IP (Google "what's my IP?" And use that) but for now you can (temporarily) use any IP `0.0.0.0/0`.

Firewall rules can be applied only to the VM running your container too, but I'd not worry about that initially.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you hit this bump as well :>

- I installed docker.io version 20.10 (default) on a Debian 11 GCP VM
- I configure a Nginx docker and opened the FW

The docker Nginx was accessible from the host but not from the internet :(

- I used tcpdump to verify the internet request traffic arrives on the host
- At last I removed the docker.io 20.10 and installed docker 24.0.6

After the upgrade the Nginx docker was accessible from the internet :)

The only change i noticed after the upgrade is the additional port export:
`:::7070->80/tcp`
[image: Extra port export]